# GET request working but POST doesn't, Twitter Api using php (without libraries)

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm actually working on twitter api and get some difficulties.

My GET request are working fine (With Oauth1 so I correctly generate signature, nonce and all the others required stuff by twitter api.

But when I try a POST request I got the code 32 error message "Could no authenticate you".

I changed my options to the following :
[Options list for cUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDNEf.png)

and the content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

So do you have any idea of what the problem could be ?

My authorization string look like that :

> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
> oauth_nonce=2005939658,
> oauth_signature=0J5GFS0a0%2FClDvslG%2FWrhTYNbeQ%3D,
> oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=NOW(),
> oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN,
> oauth_version=1.0

My problem is similor to
[Authentication no longer works after GET to POST change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134000/authentication-no-longer-works-after-get-to-post-change?answertab=votes#tab-top)
(same code used) and
[Twitter API Issue: OAuth Request Token using GET works, POST fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795830/twitter-api-issue-oauth-request-token-using-get-works-post-fails)

Ask me if you need any extra informations, thanks

**EDIT :**

The solution was the following : The text (status message) sending to build the signature and the text used in cUrl request was not the same
(thanks to @CBroe)

Comment: The request method needs to be included in the signature generation, so did you _modify_ that part accordingly, when you tried to switch methods?

Comment: just to make sure: in your code, CONSUMER_KEY and OAUTH_TOKEN are replaced by correct values, right?

Comment: @CBroe No I didn't do that, I will try it and come back to you, thank you, EDIT : Yeah I included the POST method in the base string which used to generate signature. So look's good for that part

Comment: @jasie Yeah right !

Comment: Damn @CBroe Thanks a lot, you help me to find the solution, it was because the text (status) sending to build the signature and the text used in cUrl request was not the same !